# '+=' produces '()'. How can i return an incremented value from a closure

Tags: swift, swift3

i'm using Swift3. This syntax gives me an error:

```
func countingClosure() -> (() -> Int) {
    var counter = 0
    let incrementCounter: () -> Int = {
        return counter+=1;
    }
    return incrementCounter
}
```

I cant increment using counter++, since its deprecated.
Is there a alegant way to deal with this, so the first value i return will be 0 ?
I "hacky" way will be to initiate counter = -1. And increment it a line before.

```
counter+=1;
return counter;
```

Thanks.

Edit:
I've tried to search StackOverflow for this error, and didn't find an answer. This question was marked as duplicate, but there was no way i could find the relevant/original question.

Comment: You can store the counter value in a separate variable before incrementing it, or use `defer`. Examples for both approaches in the linked-to Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another way, use `defer` to increment counter after return

```
func countingClosure() -> (() -> Int) {
    var counter = 0
    let incrementCounter: () -> Int = {
        defer {
            counter += 1
        }
        return counter
    }
    return incrementCounter
}
```